# how can I read data from json array and pass it from one fragment to another fragment and show it in a recyclerview?

Tags: android, json, android-recyclerview

Its the data for a quiz, which include "id" as question ID and "test_id" as a quiz ID. I need to fetch all the question(no. of question may differ) and options with correct answer and need to populate it in a recyclerview.

```
[  
{  
"id":"13",
"test_id":"1",
"question":"find out relationship with the third word.",
"options":"[\"speed\",\"hiking\",\"needle\",\"direction\"]",
"correct_answer":"3",
"create_date":"2016-10-27 07:37:39",
"update_date":null
},
{  
"id":"14",
"test_id":"1",
"question":"find out which of the answer choices completes the same relationship with the third word.",
"options":"[\"not\",\"set\",\"get\",\"pet\"]",
"correct_answer":"3",
"create_date":"2016-10-28 07:37:39",
"update_date":null
},
{  
"id":"15",
"test_id":"1",
"question":"the same relationship with the third word.",
"options":"[\"jet\",\"read\",\"nor\",\"sour\"]",
"correct_answer":"3",
"create_date":"2016-10-28 10:37:39",
"update_date":null
},
{  
"id":"16",
"test_id":"1",
"question":"A good way to figure out the relationship ",
"options":"[\"trekking\",\"hiking\",\"seed\",\"turn\"]",
"correct_answer":"3",
"create_date":"2016-10-28 18:37:39",
"update_date":null
}
]
```

I have used this code:

```
String res = new QuestionRequest(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "level_question").execute(test_id).get();

JSONArray result = new JSONArray(res);

List<DataQuestion> data=new ArrayList<>();


for(int i=0;i<result.length();i++){
                    JSONObject json_data = result.getJSONObject(i);
                    DataQuestion rowdata = new DataQuestion();
                    rowdata.id= json_data.getString("id");
                    rowdata.test_id= json_data.getString("test_id");
                    rowdata.question= json_data.getString("question");
                    rowdata.answer_choices= json_data.getString("answer_choices");
                    rowdata.correct_answer= json_data.getString("correct_answer");
                    data.add(rowdata);
                }
```

I have stored it in arraylist. Now how should send it another fragment. I tried to send data using Bundle but don't know how to send arraylist.

where:
DataQuestion.java is

```
public class DataQuestion {
public String id;
public String test_id;
public String question;
public String answer_choices;
public String correct_answer;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use the library Retrofit (https://square.github.io/retrofit/) to call API request and serialize the response. In your case you will create a class with many field (id, test_id, question, options,...).

And then you create an adapter for your recyclerview which accept your model class. And finally you display your item with cardview for example.

Answer (score 0):

Its better if you post what you have tried to parse this json. Parsing json is very easy in android you just have to create this a JSONArray or JSONObject from the data you have. In your case its a JSONArray.

Later you can create your models which will contain the json data , you can pass the model to a adapter and user that adapter in a recyclerview or list.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Volley to fetch the data and create a JSONObject to parse the Response into a list of Questions (using model) and then pass that list to an adapter where you can set the question in your list item in RecyclerView/ListView.